# TR, TH, TD was created but TABLE NOT

Tags: django, django-forms

i Need understand it but not be able to.

My ClassForm (**in view**):

```
class FormContact(forms.Form):
    name    = forms.CharField(label='Nome', max_length=100, required=False)
    subject = forms.CharField(label='Assunto', max_length=100, required=False)
    message = forms.CharField(label='Mensagem', widget=forms.Textarea, required=False)
```

My extended Template:

```
{% extends 'site.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}

    <form class="contato" id="contato" action="{% url 'contato' %}" method="post">
        <h1>Contato</h1>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>    
    
    <script src="{% static 'js/form_contact.js' %}"></script>
    
{% endblock %}
```

Now,

in the navigator (**inspector -> elements**)

```
<form class="contato" id="contato" action="/contato/" method="post">
    <h1>Contato</h1>
    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="???">        
    <label for="id_name">Nome:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="100" id="id_name">
    <label for="id_subject">Assunto:</label>
    <input type="text" name="subject" maxlength="100" id="id_subject">
    <label for="id_message">Mensagem:</label>
    <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="10" id="id_message"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
/form>
```

AND, in the navigator (**Ctrl+U**) View Code

```
<form class="contato"  id="contato" action="/contato/" method="post">

  <h1>Contato</h1>
  
  <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="????">
  
   <tr>
    <th><label for="id_name">Nome:</label></th>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="100" id="id_name">
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <th><label for="id_subject">Assunto:</label></th>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="subject" maxlength="100" required id="id_subject">
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <th><label for="id_message">Mensagem:</label></th>
    <td>            
      <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="10" required id="id_message"></textarea>            
    </td>
    </tr>
    
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  
</form>
```

My **doubt** is:

Why, in the **Ctrl+U**, was created the elements **TR, TH and TD** but **TABLE** not?

I can't understand it

It is this form same?

Comment: instead of  {{form}}  in your template  write  {{form.as_table}}

Comment: sorry, it, ***{{form.as_table}}***, should be insert a table block in the template or i dont undertand corretly?

Comment: you hav to add the table and inside table you have to add the {{form.as_table}}  which renders  the form elements as tr's  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/form-as_table-render-django-forms-as-table/

Comment: i understand now. But, exists any way of to do without <table>? or it is need?

Comment: as table   renders  only tr's